# Java - Compressed String

Tags: java, string

Given a string, I want to compress the string based on each character's number of consecutive occurrences next to it. For example, let's say we have a string like `"abaasass"`. `'a'` occurs one time, `'b'` occurs one time, 'a' occurs two times consecutively, `'s'` occurs one time, `'a'` occurs one time, and `'s'` occurs two times consecutively. The method should then return a string like `"aba2sas2"`.

This is what I have so far:

```
public static String compressedString(String message) {
        StringBuilder compressedString = new StringBuilder();
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < message.length() - 1; i++){
            if (message.charAt(i) == message.charAt(i+1)){
                total += 2;
                compressedString.append(message.charAt(i)).append(total);
            }
            else {
                compressedString.append(message.charAt(i));
            }
            total = 0;
        }
        return compressedString.toString();
    }
```

It instead returns: `"aba2asas2"` which is somewhat close, anyone sees the issue?

Comment: I see a host of issues. Try putting in a string with 3 or more consecutive characters.

Comment: A quick google for Java run length encoding should bring up a plethora of correct implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static String compressedString(String message) {
    StringBuilder compressedString = new StringBuilder();
    int total = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < message.length() - 1; i++){
        if (message.charAt(i) == message.charAt(i+1)){
            total++;
        }
        else if(total==1){
            compressedString.append(message.charAt(i));
        }
        else 
        {
            compressedString.append(message.charAt(i)).append(total);
            total = 1;
        }
    }
    if(message.charAt(message.length()-2) != message.charAt(message.length()-1)
        compressedString.append(message.charAt(message.length()-1));
    else
        compressedString.append(message.charAt(message.length()-1)).append(total);

    return compressedString.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static String compressedString(String message)
{
    String result = "" ;
    
    for ( int i = 0, t = message.length() - 1 ; i < t ; )
    {
        String letter = String.valueOf( message.charAt(i) ) ;
        int currentChain = consec( i, message ) ;
        
        result += ( currentChain > 1 ? ( letter + currentChain ) : letter ) ;
        
        i += currentChain ;

    }
    return result ;
}

private static int consec( int startIndex, String text )
{
    int chain = 1 ;
    
    for( int i = startIndex ; i < text.length() - 1 ; ++i )
    {
        if( text.charAt(i) == text.charAt(i+1) )
            chain++ ;
        else
            break ;
    }
    
    return chain ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your solution for your question

```
static void compressedString(String str) {
    int n = str.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        // Count occurrences of current character
        int count = 1;
        while (i < n - 1 && str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i + 1)) {
            count++;
            i++;
        }

        if (count == 1) {
            System.out.print(str.charAt(i));
        } else {
            System.out.print(str.charAt(i));
            System.out.print(count);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "abaasass";
    compressedString(str);
}
```